# Tooltip transitions not working using reactstrap

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I'm trying to show tooltips using reactstrap. The tooltips appears correctly but without fade-in/out transitions. Using the inspector I noticed that the class `fade` does not get applied to the tooltip `<div>`:

[image: tooltip]

I followed the installation instructions on https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactstrap#adding-bootstrap adding these dependencies to my `package.json` using `yarn`:

```
"bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
"react": "^16.7.0",
"react-dom": "^16.3.2",
"react-popper": "^1.3.2",
"react-transition-group": "^2.5.3",
"reactstrap": "^7.1.0",
```

This is an example component of tooltip usage taken from my app:

```
import React from 'react';
import nanoid from 'nanoid';
import {UncontrolledTooltip} from 'reactstrap';

export default class ExampleTooltip extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._id = `autogeneratedid-${nanoid()}`;
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <>
                    <span id={this._id}>Hover me!</span>
                    <UncontrolledTooltip target={this._id}>
                        My tooltip
                    </UncontrolledTooltip>
                </>
            );
    }
}
```

I'm including bootstrap using SASS in my `index.js` file:

```
import '../styles/style.scss';
```

And in my `style.scss`:

```
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

Am I missing something?

I created a codesandbox on https://codesandbox.io/s/01zm5k5w10

Thank you.

Comment: you added this 2 libraries too? react-transition-group, react-popper? this 2 libraries are effected on tooltips and there not added automatic

Comment: Yes, those two library are installed, see my `package.json` above: `"react-popper": "^1.3.2", "react-transition-group": "^2.5.3",`

Comment: Are you sure that you include this file: reactstrap.full.min.js and not this file: reactstrap.min.js ? according to their docs here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/reactstrap#versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is not on the CSS/SASS  - it's not some class that you are missing or not includes - but its something in you're react/js because it's not applied the "fade show" classes to the wrapper div like on the docs website.

[image]

Edit - Its looks like they have some issue on their code - all the real example of reactstrap except for their documentation site - have the same issue with fade effect - for example, [your sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/01zm5k5w10), a lot of examples from codepen that i cant paste here and more.

when you looking for this issue in GitHub you can see [some Discussions](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/pull/1364) about it - I think that there is something on library and not something in your code.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it too, but that `div` is created by `reactstrap`, not by me. I created a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/01zm5k5w10 showing the problem.

Comment: You are probably right, that PR seems linked to my issue. I started from their (working!) samples so I was blaming my code, I opened an issue on their github.

Comment: They confirmed that transitions are not yet released https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1370

Answer (score 0):

have you check the styles.css in devtool ?
inspect => sources